# Compress Craft Control Panel CSS and JS per environment

Tags: control-panel, multi-environment, performance

Is there a way to compress the Craft CSS for a specific environment?

Currently there is a setting for Javascript, `useCompressedJs`, set to true by default.

> **useCompressedJs**
>
> Tells Craft whether to use compressed Javascript files whenever possible, to cut down on page load times.
>
> https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#useCompressedJs

Is it possible to have a similar option in general.php for CSS?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's anything built into Craft. What I do is

```
{% if craft.config.devMode %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{craft.config.environmentVariables['assetURL']}}css/style.css">
{% else %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{craft.config.environmentVariables['assetURL']}}css/style.min.css">
{% endif %}
```

I use `devMode` to control whether or not I want the minified css, and I use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)'s [cssmin task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin) to build my minified css.

Comment: That  is a great tip for front end CSS. However, I am referring to resources for crafts control panel. I cleaned up the question to clear that up.